# codeigniter hmvc module helper

Tags: codeigniter, module, helper, hmvc

i made module comments, it requiers my custom helper to work, how can i store helper in module folder instead application/helpers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can just create a `helpers` folder within your `module` directory, and load it as you would normally.

Comment: yep it works but to load module helper must use

$this->load->helper('<module_name>/<helper_name>')